Tabularray error when using standalone
I have a large tabularray table I want to have as a separate pdf (like tikzexternailze). The code works fine when using report as document class, however when using the standalone class it throws this error: "
You can't use "\prevdepth" in restricted horizontal mode.
This only happens when using the crop (normal) mode of standalone, while the preview mode works just fine, but only gives me a cut off version of the table. I also found a comment saying it might be due to LaTeX3.
Does anyone have experience / knowledge with the standalone class or a possible alternative? (was just the first and really one one I found)
MWE (works with "preview" as setting for the standalone class but not without)
\documentclass[12pt,pdftex, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Long Table},
  ]{
    colspec={|c|X[15 cm,m,l]|X[1,m,c]|}
  }
  \hline[1pt]
  & Foo & Bar \\\hline[0.8pt]
  TEST & short text & 1 \\\cline{2-3} 
  & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 2 \\\cline{2-3} 
  & short text & 4 \\\cline{2-3} 
  & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 5 \\\cline{2-3} 
  & very long text ....... ......... ........ ....... ....... ....... ........ ............. ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... needs lots of lines & 6 \\\hline[1pt]
  \end{longtblr}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem?

by default standalone is like \mbox so it can clip to the content size, so it can not have vertical display material, it has an option to allow that

just added a MWE

@DavidCarlisle do you know how to do that? Sorry this out of range of my TeX knowledge.

Using the article class and the showframe package shows that your table is too large for the page:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Long Table},
  ]{
    colspec={|c|X[15 cm,m,l]|X[1,m,c]|}
  }
  \hline[1pt]
  & Foo & Bar \\\hline[0.8pt]
  TEST & short text & 1 \\\cline{2-3}
  & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 2 \\\cline{2-3}
  & short text & 4 \\\cline{2-3}
  & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 5 \\\cline{2-3}
  & very long text ....... ......... ........ ....... ....... ....... ........ ............. ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... needs lots of lines & 6 \\\hline[1pt]
  \end{longtblr}

\end{document}


With standalone and the preview option, only the portion inside the margins is kept:

Simply use a larger paper, like with
\usepackage[a0paper, landscape]{geometry}

Example:
\documentclass[12pt,pdftex,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[a0paper, landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
  \begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Long Table},
  ]{
    colspec={|c|X[15 cm,m,l]|X[1,m,c]|}
  }
  \hline[1pt]
  & Foo & Bar \\\hline[0.8pt]
  TEST & short text & 1 \\\cline{2-3}
  & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 2 \\\cline{2-3}
  & short text & 4 \\\cline{2-3}
  & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 5 \\\cline{2-3}
  & very long text ....... ......... ........ ....... ....... ....... ........ ............. ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... needs lots of lines & 6 \\\hline[1pt]
  \end{longtblr}

\end{document}



This is much more elegant than mine. Thanks!

I have now found an okay way of circumventing this problem. I am now using a0paper and landscape together with the report class. Additionally I have the geometry package with margin set to 0cm and also pagestyle as empty. This way I have a large clean slate to work on. Afterwards S just apply pdfcrop on the pdf file to get the pdf containing the table without any margins. I have also added \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} to remove the "Table1:" tag above the table.
My working example is now the following:
\documentclass[a0paper,11pt,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Long Table},
  ]{
    colspec={|c|X[15 cm,m,l]|X[1cm,m,c]|}
  }
    \hline[1pt]
    & Foo & Bar \\\hline[0.8pt]
    TEST & short text & 1 \\\cline{2-3} 
    & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 2 \\\cline{2-3} 
    & short text & 4 \\\cline{2-3} 
    & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 5 \\\cline{2-3} 
    & very long text ....... ......... ........ ....... ....... ....... ........ ............. ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... needs lots of lines & 6 \\\hline[1pt]
  \end{longtblr}

\end{document}

This produces in the end the following:


